# Pass Date Parameter From PHP to Crystal Report

Tags: php, parameters, crystal-reports

I am having substantial trouble passing a date parameter to the Crystal Reports 11 component from PHP5 on Windows. It should be easy, of course, but the various commented-out items don't seem to work:

```
<?php
$my_report = "C:\\xampp\htdocs\wincare\laporan\adm_JumlahPasienPoli.rpt"; // rpt source file
$my_pdf = "C:\\xampp\htdocs\wincare\laporan\adm_JumlahPasienPoli.pdf"; // RPT export to pdf file
//-Create new COM object-depends on your Crystal Report version
$ObjectFactory= new COM("CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1") or die ("Error on load"); // call COM port
$crapp = $ObjectFactory-> CreateObject("CrystalDesignRunTime.Application.11"); // create an instance for Crystal
$creport = $crapp->OpenReport($my_report,1); // call rpt report

// to refresh data before

//- Set database logon info - must have
$creport->Database->Tables(1)->SetLogOnInfo("localhost", "db_wincare", "sa", "sa");

//- field prompt or else report will hang - to get through
$creport->EnableParameterPrompting = 0;



// this is the error 

$zz = $creport->ParameterFields(1)->SetCurrentValue("2011-01-01 00:00:00");    

//export to PDF process
$creport->ExportOptions->DiskFileName=$my_pdf; //export to pdf
$creport->ExportOptions->PDFExportAllPages=true;
$creport->ExportOptions->DestinationType=1; // export to file
$creport->ExportOptions->FormatType=31; // PDF type
$creport->Export(false);

//------ Release the variables ------
$creport = null;
$crapp = null;
$ObjectFactory = null;

//------ Embed the report in the webpage ------
print "<embed src=\"adm_JumlahPasienPoli.pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\">"



?>
```

and the messege :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message
>   '**Source:** 
> **Description:** ' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wincare\laporan\pakai.php:36 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wincare\laporan\pakai.php(36):
>   variant->SetCurrentValue('2011-01-01 00:0...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wincare\laporan\pakai.php on line 36

Comment: Heh, just spotted this after answering your PM. +1 :) (You may wish to hyperlink the SitePoint thread to demonstrate the research you've done, and to say that those things didn't work for you.)

Comment: I don't have a solution aside from the one I've already posted. But, for what it's worth, the data you're passing is the **second** parameter, right? Remember that the first parameter is likely to be `$creport->ParameterFields(0)`

Comment: (As per discussion on my answer, I have rolled the latest OP edit back. Editing questions to ask a different one is not a good approach, since existing answers are then placed out of context. Please ask a new question).

Answer (score 1):

I remember spending a long time on this question some five years ago, and eventually finding a hacky but working answer:

```
// This block is strictly guesswork
$application = new COM("CrystalRuntime.Application.9"); // Change to your version
$report = $application->OpenReport($my_report,1);       // From OP's code
$rptParams = $report.ParameterFields
$rptParam = $rptParams->Item(2);                        // From my SitePoint post; 
                                                        // obviously you need to use
                                                        // the right index

// Check that $rptParam->ValueType evaluates to 10 - if it does not
// then modify the type in Crystal Reports itself. Again, see my
// original solution

// This bit should be fine
$oScript = new COM("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl");
$oScript->Language = "VBScript";
$oScript->AllowUI = false;
$oScript->AddObject('rptParam', $rptParam, true);
$oScript->AddCode('Function SetDateParameter(strDate)
rptParam.AddCurrentValue(CDate(strDate))
End Function');
$oScript->Run("SetDateParameter", "25 April 2006");
```

This worked fine, but it's not very elegant! Worked on CR9 with Windows Server 2003, I think. Copied from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?486356-Inserting-date-parameters-into-a-Crystal-report&viewfull=1#post3445617) - was prior to the birth of StackExchange `:)`.

Comment: OP - you previously indicated this didn't work for you. If that is correct, add to your question your attempt using this approach, and show what errors you got.

Comment: the following error i get :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Parameter 1: Type mismatch. ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cr.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\cr.php(29): com->AddObject('rptParam', NULL, true) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wincare\laporan\pakai.php on line 29

what i should fill the $rptParam value?

Comment: Ah yes, `$rptParam` was not defined - you should switch on warnings so you can see this sort of thing. I've tried to help by adding a new section, which _is mainly guesswork_. You are in a **much** stronger position to work this out, since you can fire up a VB editor in your Windows/CR environment, and use autocomplete to work out what methods/attributes to use.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class variant could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ex\cr.php on line 23

Comment: @N'dongAbdulGani - great! Please tick my answer (it's what we do here to express appreciation). Also, please consider adding your own answer to show people what modifications you made for CR11 (you may get rep points for doing so).

Comment: sure halfer :)

but i wanna ask again,

how to pass more than one parameters???

@halfer, how :)

Comment: @N'dongAbdulGani - please roll back your last question edit, and ask a new question. It is considered bad form to edit a question to ask another, since the old answers then won't make sense. (Alert me when you've done that, if you like).

Comment: I had the same issue as the question starter, and this worked perfectly. Big thank you!